# Removing a string character in list Python

Tags: python, django, data-structures

I have the data in a dictionary format, as below; i want to remove the '`"` 'character in list. how can i achieve that? 
Any help, would be much appreciated.

output:

```
{
"test2": [
    [
        "'testdesc...', ' fdfd', '  dsgdgdfgdfg'"
    ]
   ]
}
```

desire output:

```
{
"test2": [
    [
        'testdesc...', ' fdfd', '  dsgdgdfgdfg'
    ]
   ]
}
```

I tried something like this in my views, but it won't reflect any changes.

views.py :

```
for record in data:
    test_list = []
    test_list.append(record['description'])
    record['test2'] = [x.split(' " ') for x in test_list]
```

Comment: for the text you shown, what is your desired output?

Comment: There is no `"` character in your string. The `"..."` are just the "boundaries" of the string literal, but the string itself does *not* contain any  quotes `"`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean, i can not remove that character just because it's coming by default as "boundaries" ?

Comment: @anonymoususer: if you write a string `"foobar"`, then `"` is *not* part of the *content* of a string, it is only used to specify a *string literal*.

Answer (score 0):

you can first replace the single quotes with nothing ("") and then split the whole string by ',' like this:

```
>>> list(map(str,c['test2'][0][0].replace("'","").split(',')))
```

This will return a list with the desired strings in a list:

['testdesc...', '  fdfd', '   dsgdgdfgdfg']